# AJAXing Content into a Page with JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've built a webpage, and in the webpage is a div, which then is filled from an AJAX call with the following content:-

```
<div class="latest-jobs">
    <ul class="list-of-jobs">
        <li>
            <div class="job">
                <h3><a href="">Job Title</a></h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><span>Location</span></li>
                    <li><span>JOb Type</span></li>
                    <li><span>Salary</span></li>
                    <li><span>Ref: JOB-REF-1</span></li>
                </ul>
                Description
                <a href="#">more &gt;</a>
            </div>
        </li> 
        <li>
            <div class="job">
                <h3><a href="">Job Title</a></h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><span>Location</span></li>
                    <li><span>JOb Type</span></li>
                    <li><span>Salary</span></li>
                    <li><span>Ref: JOB-REF-1</span></li>
                </ul>
                Description
                <a href="#">more &gt;</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="job">
                <h3><a href="">Job Title</a></h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><span>Location</span></li>
                    <li><span>JOb Type</span></li>
                    <li><span>Salary</span></li>
                    <li><span>Ref: JOB-REF-1</span></li>
                </ul>
                Description
                <a href="#">more &gt;</a>
            </div>
        </li> 
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(SlickSlider,2000);
</script>
```

That function initializes the plugin for the SlickSlider plugin (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), but Google Chrome returns the following console error:-

"Uncaught ReferenceError: SlickSlider is not defined"

I think this is something to do with the scope in which the function call and the script are located. The SlickSlider function does exist in a JavaScript file at the bottom of the page, but I think because the call to that function is inside the AJAX loaded div, it cannot see the JS function in the file at the bottom of the page?

As soon as I call the function from somewhere not inside the AJAX loaded area, the function can be found.

Can anyone suggest on how I can make the function call not return the above error?

Cheers!

**EDIT**
Added the JS function here:-

```
function SlickSlider() {
    if ($('.blue-section .list-of-jobs').length) {
        $('.blue-section .list-of-jobs').slick({
            autoplay: false,
            centerMode: false,
            nextArrow: '<span class="right-btn next-page"><i class="icon"></i></span>',
            prevArrow: '<span class="left-btn prev-page"><i class="icon"></i></span>',
            dots: false,
            infinite: true,
            variableWidth: false,
            speed: 300,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            responsive: [
              {
                  breakpoint: 1170,
                  settings: {
                      slidesToShow: 2,
                      slidesToScroll: 2,
                      infinite: true
                  }
              },
              {
                  breakpoint: 600,
                  settings: {
                      slidesToShow: 1,
                      slidesToScroll: 2
                  }
              },
              {
                  breakpoint: 480,
                  settings: {
                      slidesToShow: 1,
                      slidesToScroll: 1
                  }
              }
            ]
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried like   setTimeout(SlickSlider(),2000);

Comment: Can you show us how the code you use to import the SlickSlider plugin ? This could very will be that SlickSlider is not defined *yet* when you call it.

Comment: You problem seems to be with the slider init and not with ajax, you should follow the documentation here: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/, include the js and css, then initialize it

Comment: I think there is an issue with the Slick JS file to begin with, in that I can't see what I expect in the source code, had an idea about why the initialize is failing, so I'll try that and drop an answer back shortly. Thanks guys!

Comment: So SlickSlider is from you own code. Can you clarify what you mean by "filled from an AJAX call". Do you use $.load() ?

Comment: Yes, so as its live job data, we specify an empty div and this gets populated with the HTML returned. This loads a second or so after the rest of the page has finished loading (we have a loading spinner to show its processing). We don't use $.load() for this to my knowledge.

Comment: As I said before.... have you tried like setTimeout(SlickSlider(),2000); 

you need to use () to call your function

Comment: Sounds like SlickSlider isn't in the global scope. Perhaps your SlickSlider declaration is inside a function, such as a callback.

Comment: @GuilhermeSilva adding () will immediately execute the function without waiting for the timer.See this example https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/2a2t1m9v/

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestions above, I added setTimeout(SlickSlider(),500); and this gave the AJAX call enough time to bring back the HTML, and for the SlickSlider plugin to be loaded in the page. After this 1/2 second extra, the plugin works fine. I guess it was all happening to fast for the HTML to be rendered as a result of the AJAX call.

@Clayton Leis - I was worried this was the issue as well, but it appears to be just being loaded to quickly.

Cheers for everyones help!

Comment: setTimeout accepts time in milliseconds , 500 is basically 500 millisecond which is much lesser that 2000 milliseconds(2secs). So I am not sure how this is giving ajax call enough time

Comment: you are right about the 2 secs and 0.5 sec....
still
the () on your code make sense... but I think when you are loading via ajax you still need the () after the function name.

if he had used even with 2000 it would have worked